Conditional Web Component Slot Container Based on Slotted Content
Given a web component extending LitElement:
import { html, LitElement } from 'lit';
import { customElement } from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('my-element')
export class MyElement extends LitElement {
    render() {
        return html`
<div>some static content</div>
<div class="slotted"><slot></slot></div>
<div>more static content</div>
        `;
    }
}

And the component is used like this:
<my-element>${maybeContentMaybeNothing}</my-element>

Since maybeContentMaybeNothing could contain html or text or nothing at all, how can the div.slotted element be hidden if maybeContentMaybeNothing contains nothing, but shown if it contains anything?
EDIT: To clarify, it needs to be checked on load and listened to for changes ongoing.

Based on this Discord thread:
To achieve this, you basically have to use a MutationObserver to watch childList to detect slottable content and control the element's rendering accordingly.
In patternfly component library they have a controller for this in PatternFly Elements. You're welcome to use it:
Slot Controller
You can find the original discussion on Discord here.

But when there is nothing added, there is no Mutation...

I guess slot.assignedElements() will return empty in that case

If you want to hide content in shadowDOM WHEN there is no content in lightDOM
you have to wait till after lightDOM was parsed (the closing tag of your Web Component was parsed)
A Mutation Observer is required when you want to show content in shadowDOM again
A Mutation Observer can't do the hide part, since there is no Mutation to start with, unless you observe the container your Web Component is in... checking lightDOM
But that is a bit overkill.
The connectedCallback fires on the opening tag (long read) of your Web Component
Then the easiest delay is a setTimeout; after which we can check lightDOM content.


<script>
  customElements.define("hide-slot-container", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super() // sets AND returns 'this' scope
        .attachShadow({mode:"open"}) // sets AND returns this.shadowRoot
        .innerHTML =
          `<style>` +
          ` :host( [lightdom]       ) .container{ background:lightgreen }` +
          ` :host( :not([lightdom]) ) .container{ background:lightcoral }` +
          `</style>` +
          `<div>some static content</div>` +
          `<div class="container"><slot>No lightDOM content</slot></div>` +
          `<div>more static content</div>`
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => this.toggleAttribute("lightdom", this.innerHTML !== ''));
    }
  })
</script>
<hide-slot-container></hide-slot-container>
<hide-slot-container>lightDOM content</hide-slot-container>



notes

If you are going to add named slots, you have to check each <slot> for assignedElements()

This only renders state once, for dynamic behavior, you need that Mutation Observer and/or slotchange event, depending on your requirements


